# Disable @media print in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to entirely disable any preconfigured `@media print` css styles from `bootstrap` without having to recompile it?

The print styles applied by default could be seen here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6837

I want my webpage to be printed just as seen, with all css tags applied. Especially colors, like:

```
b {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

In order to disable the print styles from bootstrap, I'd have to explicit override *every* property again with my custom styles, eg:

```
b {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

But isn't there a global way to disable these default print styles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download custom bootstrap without media print.
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

just uncheck

> Print media styles

Comment: Hm that's nice in general, but I'd like to stick to the remote stylesheet imports, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`.

Comment: Then you could create your own maxcdn link with the custom downloaded boostrap

Comment: Possibly there is not better solution and probably not possible to "deactivate" the css print tags entirely.

Comment: @membersound - I have a long winded explanation in agreement [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color/36742058#36742058).