# Bootstrap print

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, I use npm to install bootstrap. The website should be printable, so the basic bootstrap print style is nice. But I need the text colors. Sadly the default bootstrap removes all colors.

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
}
```

I want to "revert" that color setting, but don't want to / can't change the bootstrap files as they are deployed and installed on rollout.

Has anyone an idea how to overwrite that setting with a custom css?

Comment: just declare a new statement after the you loaded the bootstrap file? That overwrites the value, without changing the original file

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

to fix color problems with my style sheets...

Comment: This does not help, as bootstrap overwrites all font colors with "!important".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare an identical selector to override it, presuming your custom CSS is loaded after Bootstrap's.

i.e.

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    color: /* some other color /*
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I want to have it to the original color. So if a text was green, it should be green on the print page, if it was red ... But it looks like I have to rewrite the color styles for the print page.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood the ask there Kim. From this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color) and my own knowledge, you'll have to rewrite them if you can't customize your Bootstrap at all. That's unfortunate since the Bootstrap site does let you download a custom build that excludes the print styles.