# R Markdown HTML Output in Chrome loses coloring when print to PDF from Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, r-markdown

For Example:

***Series/Episode: `r paste0(stats['this_week_episode'])`***      *-`r paste0(stats['this_week_debut_date'])`*

---

Within the HTML view in Chrome the coloring is blue. However, when I print to PDF from Chrome I lose all formatting. This doesn't happen with other web pages (google, indeed etc.) which leads me to believe it's an R Markdown setting or formatting function.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This answer gives you some insight about this behavior https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742058/1777111