# Print css being ignored Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap4 project where the user needs to be able to print the page. I have a print.css file that I have a few obnoxious styles it just to see if the styles are taking effect and they are not.

My styles are

```
@media print {
    body{background-color:green;}
    p{color:red;}
}
```

Could there be something with bootstrap preventing the styles? The print is not even taking on bootstrap styles.

My link looks like this

```
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

I have also tried changing the media type to all and that was a fail as well.

This is not about the background color. I have many display:none;'s in there as well that are not being read either. I only used the background color as a test and example.

Comment: What's the order of your CSS files being included?

Comment: Is the sheet even being loaded?

Comment: @Luicy, the print is the last style sheet being included

Comment: @j08691, yes the stylesheet is on the page

Comment: What do you mean by the stylesheet is on the page? Have you checked the network/sources/console tabs of the developer tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap print CSS removes background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color)

Comment: @j08691, yes I have checked the network tab and sources. The stylesheet is being loaded.

Comment: Just a guess, but when I call files I use the `~` symbol before.. so in your case `~/css/print.css`

Comment: bootstrap has its own print styles and can not be override.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, those are not even being loaded....

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, this is not just about background color. I don't care about the background color...I just need something to work...

Comment: @zazvorniki I know the tittle says background, but they talk about the others properties as well. I recomend you to take a look at it

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, I have read that. The bootstrap styles for the print are not even coming through. All styles are being stripped.

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong but give it a shot,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

I believe you're actually missing the Type and with my understanding it's not needed but may be for a print doc.

Let me know how it works or if it does, make sure this is at the top of the list of Links just to clarify that's not the problem too.

Just read a comment on your question and I believe they're right about bootstrap having it's own print stylesheet but I'm sure it can be overwritten. If not don't worry too much about it. I've just finished developing a site and as long as your code is correct and layed out right it should sort itself out, or atleast mine did :'D

Comment: Sadness, worth a try anyway aha. Check out the last section I just added you may be saved by the love of bootstrap

Comment: The bootstrap print css is not even loading. It is just stripping out all styles and is unacceptable...I need to fix this and worry about this...

Comment: To be honest buddy, It seems like it may be pointing to the wrong direction, Are you getting any errors in the console? If not maybe add ../ or .../ and depending where you index.php/index.html is set you may have to add a couple]

Comment: No errors, the files are loading correctly in the network tab from the console so I know that the link is pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried checking in other browsers? Can't see this being the case but have a lookie, if not the check the link in the dev tools, see if the <link> is there, if it is, try resolve the file location, try to open said stylesheet in chrome, either using CTRL+U and open that way or within dev tools. If it doesn't open then you're pointing to the wrong directory

Comment: Ignore the last bit, you replied as I was typing that aha, make sure it's not just chrome being a **** :')

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately It's not just chrome. But even if it was I would still have to fix it. Large large project where they print a lot

Answer (score -2):

You could try adding it to your main stylesheet with an @media and see if that works

```css
@media print {
  /*styles here*/
}
```

Comment: The styles are extensive for what I need to do and I need a separate stylesheet.