# r color disappear in printing

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I made a markdown in html, using kable on a dataframe. I set a background color, it works on the browser, but when i want to print paper, the color disappear... I would like to do a layout too (page break, jump line), i searched, i saw some code, i tested, but nothing works...

The code for color :

```
kable(tableEvo,"html",
               booktabs=T,
               caption=paste("Fonds et Benchmarks respectifs au",format(ajd,"%d-%m-%Y"),sep(" "))%>%
               kable_styling("basic","condensed")%>%
               row_spec(c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26),background="#33FFFF")%>%
               column_spec(1:5,bold=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `tableEvo` so this problem is reproducible? Also, does it matter whether you print HTML directly to paper, or would it be OK to render a PDF or Word doc that you then print?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the printer than a problem with programming. Have you tried a different colour?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually bootstrap's fault. It will take away all your background color when print.

See [Bootstrap print CSS removes background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color)

I will try to open up the webpage in Safari and check "print background" on the printing page.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to put *!important* behind the color name in the code.

For instance if the background color chosen is red, write:

```
 background = "red !important"
```

This worked for me.

Thanks to Hao, for clarifying this for me over e-mail.